# Check if UIContentContainer is ViewContoller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, swift3

I am translating Apple's sample [Custom View Controller Presentations and Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/CustomTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015158) (specifically the AAPLCustomPresentationController) into Swift, and I've stumbled into a problem.

In their preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer method (line 190) they check

```
- (void)preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:(id<UIContentContainer>)container
{
    [super preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:container];

    if (container == self.presentedViewController)
        [self.containerView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

In Swift (3.0), I tried

```
if container == (self.presentedViewController as UIContentContainer)
```

But I get the error

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'UIContentContainer' operands

How can I perform this check in Swift?

Comment: `UIContentContainer` protocol does not conform to `Equatable` protocol, so you cannot use ==

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both objects are UIViewControllers, maybe cast them as that type before comparing?

```
if presentedViewController as? UIViewController == container as? UIViewController {
    // true
}
```